# Reverse selection in ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to find out the counties that don't contain any stores in ArcGIS using python.

I have a point layer (representing the stores) and a polygon layer (counties). I have managed to write some code to find out the counties that DO contain the stores. The code is below.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
path="C:/Users/XARDAS/Documents/ArcGIS/Packages/Romania1000k_9E5B7FEC-6005-4D3A-81EA-E95FAACEF69E/v101/ro1mil.gdb"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(path+"/Counties", "Counties_lyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(path+"/Stores", "Stores_lyr")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Stores_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION","Type=1")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Counties_lyr","INTERSECT","Stores_lyr",0,"NEW_SELECTION")
```

So this gives me the counties that have stores but I would like to somehow inverse the intersection for the program to give me the ones that don't have any stores. I have thought about just deleting the selected counties but I don't think that it would be too nice.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/243021/115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have selected everything that you don't want selected, inverting (or switching) the selection will give you what you want. ([ref help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm))

Add this line at the end:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Counties_lyr", "SWITCH_SELECTION")
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works but SelectLayerByLocation allows you to invert the selection within the function:

```py
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Counties_lyr","INTERSECT","Stores_lyr",0,"NEW_SELECTION","INVERT")
```